# Fuerte - kdl_conversions package missing

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, kdl, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently downloaded the latest arm_navigation (from https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/armnavigation) for my recent Fuerte install. However when I attempt to build the arm_kinematics_constraint_aware package, I get the following error.

> arm_navigation/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/kdl_arm_kinematics_plugin.cpp:35:37: fatal error: kdl_conversions/kdl_msg.h: No such file or directory

I double checked and there is indeed no kdl_conversions package in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (let alone in geometry, where I expected it to be).

So I downloaded the geometry package (from hg https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry) and make the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH reference it instead. However, I can't build it because it uses catkin (I tried to go through the tutorials, but I couldn't get it to work). Is there any way to get a regular version of geometry that uses rosmake for Fuerte? Or some way to get arm_navigation working without kdl_conversions?

I also ran

> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation --fix-missing

for the heck of it, but it didn't fix my problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44511/fuerte---kdl_conversions-package-missing/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-25**:
Why do you want the latest version of arm navigation?

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-09-25**:
The arm_navigation package I was using was from electric, I wanted one compatible with Fuerte after I upgraded.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-25**:
'sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-arm-navigation' will get you the latest version of arm_navigation that was released for fuerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the change list for [arm_navigation](http://ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/ChangeList), the 1.2.x releases are compiled against ROS Groovy, which has significant changes to the build infrastructure and some core packages, including geometry.

Looking at the change logs, I don't see any new features since 1.1.11, so I would just use the version available from debs.

There is no non-catkin version of the geometry package available for Fuerte. Catkin doesn't support multiple install directories, so it isn't possible to do an overlay of geometry in the same way that you can overlay older ROS stacks; this is one of the things that will be fixed with the build system updates in Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-09-25**:
How would one install an older version of the package? The wiki page for it only gives the link I tried above.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-25**:
You can get an older version of the source by checking out the release tag; 'hg update '; for the latest version from Fuerte, you can update to the fuerte tag: 'hg update fuerte' or you can update to the released version tag 'hg update arm_navigation-1.1.11'

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-25**:
In general, check the releases page of a stack to see which versions you should use for which distribution: http://ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Releases

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-25**:
In general, check the releases page of a stack to see which versions you should use for which distribution: http://ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Releases